# println!() only if object implements Debug trait

Tags: rust

I have method in my struct, that takes generic type `T`. The type may implement `Debug` trait, but it is not required by my struct.
I need to debug my application, and having the possibility to print it would be very useful. Unfortunately, I can't do it as the type may not implement `Debug` trait. I could specify the `T: Debug` in my struct definition, but I need to add it in a lot of places for my code to compile.
Is it possible to invoke `println!()` macro only when the type implements this trait?

Something like this:

```rust
if argument.implements(Debug) {
    println!("{:?}", argument);
}
```

Comment: please provide a complete example, you could just add a additional constraint on T for a specific function

Comment: As I mentioned - I know that I can do that, but that would require too many changes in the code, as the argument is passed through multiple methods and structs. A complete example would be too big.

Comment: then no there is no way to do what you want. But I would be curious to see why you think it's would change to much your code.

Comment: This reeks of Shotgun Surgery :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is currently not possible. Using any trait requires the enclosing function to have that constraint.

However, this *will* be possible when [trait specialization](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/31844) is stabilized. The [debugit](https://crates.io/crates/debugit) crate for example provides conditional debug printing when compiled with nightly.